# Replacing comma and Dollar sign from DIV class

Tags: javascript, replace

Im trying to get a string from a div that changes dynamically depending on the selected product, so, my DIV looks like this:

```html
<p class="price"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>3,450.00</span></p>
```

That price changes depending on the products selected and i need to put that into a js variable called 'precioObtenido'

So i tried this:

```html
<script>var preciosf = document.getElementsByClassName('price')[0].innerHTML;</script>
```

and i get the full value, like "$3,450.00" in this example, then i used this to remove the comma:
`<script>var precionc = preciosf.replace(/,/g, '');</script>`

That gives me "$3450.00" but when i tried to remove the dollar sign using various methods like `var precionum = precionc.replace(/\$/g, '')` or `var precionum = precionc.replace('$$', '')` it doesnt work, how can i do this?

Comment: Use `.textContent` instead of `.innerHTML`

Comment: Thank you! That worked perfectly! but now my script doesnt update the price as i change it, how can i set the variable to be always updated corresponding to the value in the div?

Answer (score 0):

Just [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) out the dollar sign:

```js
var precionc = "$3450.00";
var precionum = precionc.slice(1);
console.log(precionum);
```

The regex works too:

```js
var precionc = "$3450.00";
var precionum = precionc.replace(/\$/g, "");
console.log(precionum);
```

Comment: Nevermind, seems like it is working correctly, but other part of my code doesnt take it, if i put `precioObtenido = precionum;` my script returns `$NaN`

Using `console.log(precioObtenido);` i get `<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol"></span>3450.00</span>` so it is removing the sign and the comma, but not the rest of the html stuff, and i need only the numeric value